# Sticky navbar not getting in position correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I just made a navbar above and header, first solution was to use the `.sticky-top` but then when I decided to let appear some icons on the navbar after the navbar was crossed I got some little trouble.
Now my navbar is not getting back as it should (it sticks to the real top, above my header), I got a vertical overflow and I got stuck.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUYo.jpg) (the red container is photoshopped it's just to show you where the navbar should go)

Can you help me understan what did I do wrong? Thank you.

Navbar:

```
   <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#al-center-nav" aria-controls="al-center-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="imgs/logo.png" id="logo" height="40px" width="75px"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse center" id="al-center-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" alt="Facebook" id="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" alt="Instagram" id="ig"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
  $(window).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#navbar').offset().top) {
        $('#navbar').addClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').css('margin-left', '-70px');
        $('#fb').css('right', '0');
        $('#ig').css('right', '-70px')
      }
      else {
        $('#navbar').removeClass('sticky');
        $('#logo').css('margin-left', '-280px');
        $('.social').css('margin-left', '-290px');
        $('#fb').css('right', '-280px');
        $('#ig').css('right', '-280px')
      }
    });
  });
```

CSS:

```
  #fb {
font-size: 40px;
right: -280px;
position: absolute;
transition: all 600ms;
  }


  #ig {
    font-size: 40px;
    right: -280px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 600ms;
  }

  #logo {
    margin-left: -280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    transition: all 600ms;
  }

  #navbar {
    color: #ec8013;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: -51px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: .5rem;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding-top: 16px;
    color: #ec8013!important;
    transition: 0.2s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 55px;
  }

    .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for the navbar is set to stick it right in the top:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you can calculate the offset you need, put it in the top property, if it's `200px`, for example:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it adding z-index to the .sticky class and to the body
I calculated the position to go over with alert($('#navbar').offset().top) and everything seems working now